# iptables is deleting all ip's that i have block automatically

Tags: centos, iptables

After I do add the ip adresses that is attacking me, I do add this `iptables -A INPUT -s 109.73.162.160 -j DROP` and `service iptables save`.

The ip that I do add to my blocklist is lost within a few minuts, is there maybe an another way to block this ip adresses?

CentOS 4.0

Comment: That's weird. The rules don't disappear, may be you have another process/cronjob changing the rules.

Comment: Thanks diegows there was another firewall installed named apf, i did uninstall it and my problem was solved

Comment: Consider migrating to a newer CentOS BTW. 4.0 is too old for today. It's actually EOL'ed: http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2012-February/018462.html

Comment: Perhaps: sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, this is not a programming question, but should go to *serverfault*.

Most likely, you have installed some other firewall script that reinitializes your firewall.
Make sure you are only using *one* way of configuring your firewall, or they will interfere.

Answer (score 0):

I am not directly familiar with iptables in CentOS 4.0 (hence these are general suggestions) but I think you can add the rules to the iptables configuration file in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` in order that they are automatically loaded.

e.g. You will need to modify your iptables files to match something like this;

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1494682:129394658]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
#add your rules here
-A INPUT -s 109.73.162.160 -j DROP
#end of your rules here
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
COMMIT
```

The 2nd issue appears to be that `service iptables save` is not persisting your rules correctly. Hence I would suggest pasting some of your configs in to your question for more help. e.g.

`cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables`
`cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config`

and whether you are running `fail2ban`, `shorewall`, `ufw` or some other package or service that would likely  make changes to your configuration automatically.